# summarise_each deprecated - new summarise_at throws error

Tags: r, dplyr

I am working with the following code and data to summarize values:

```
  bvsubcount.subset %>% 
  group_by(bv.parentbvid) %>%
  summarise_each(funs(sum), c(`2003`:`2005`)) -> bvsubcount.subset
```

Date example:

```
bvsubcount.subset <- setNames(data.frame(c("AT", "DE", "IT"), c("ID1", "ID1", "ID2"),1:3,5:7,3:5), 
c("bv.sub.country.iso", "bv.parentbvid", 2003:2005))
```

So far, this worked fine, but since recently I am getting the following warning:

```
`summarise_each()` is deprecated.
Use `summarise_all()`, `summarise_at()` or `summarise_if()` instead.
To map `funs` over a selection of variables, use `summarise_at()`
```

If I use `summarise_at`, however, using the following code, I get the error Error:

```
bvsubcount.subset %>% 
  group_by(bv.parentbvid) %>%
  summarise_at(funs(sum), c(`2003`:`2005`)) -> bvsubcount.subset


.vars` must be a character/numeric vector or a `vars()` object, not list
```

How can I use the new summarise functions to avoid the warning and still use a similar code structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As the `error` is suggesting the `.vars` must be a character vector of variable names, so you can try something like this:

```
bvsubcount.subset %>% 
+     group_by(bv.parentbvid) %>%
+     summarise_at(.vars = c("2003","2004","2005"),.funs = sum) -> 
bvsubcount.subset
```

If you don't want to explicitly mention each numeric column name then replace `c("2003","2004","2005")` with `as.character(2003:2005)`

Comment: or use `summarise_at(vars(2003:2005, funs(sum))`. The problem was both arguments were unnamed and out of the default order